# kendo-angular-ui grid with pagination as well as grouping in angular2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Can we have pagination and grouping together in kendo-angular-ui grid? want to understand if this is possible in kendo grid using angular2?

I tried to create a example where I can have both grouping and pagination together, but somehow pagination is not working. 
`<kendo-grid [groupable]="false" [data]="gridView" [group]="groups" [pageSize]="pageSize" [skip]="skip" [pageable]="true" (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)">
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" [width]="80"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" [width]="300"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" [width]="120"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" title="Category">
            <ng-template kendoGridGroupHeaderTemplate let-value="value">
                {{value}}
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>`

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vw60nRCh8R53W7nLzMr5?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/grouping/grouping/) they have a working example with grouping and pagination.

Comment: Thank you, but i need an example which have both grouping and pagination working together.

Comment: And that example have BOTH working together, don't understand what else you need

Comment: ok, may be my question was not clear, please see the updated question

Comment: What about the code for that **dataStateChange** function?

Comment: it's within plunker link, which is included.

Comment: That code is broken, there is no **dataStateChange** function defined. Try this one (although you could have looked the one I linked before)... http://plnkr.co/edit/aAPUJfVFrqGaQQ05RhSU?p=preview

Comment: ohh, I am really sorry. Don't know how i was missing it this whole time.